# python object has properties on initialze

Tags: python

I created a graph node class in Python.
Each node has single parent, multiple children and properties.
An implementation should be like below:

```
# graph_test.py
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, name, prop={}):
        self.name = name
        self.properties = prop
        self.parent = None
        self.children = []
        print "New node:", self.name, self.properties
    def add_prop(self, k, v):
        self.properties.update({k:v})
        print "added prop:", k, v
    def add_child(self, n):
        self.children.append(n)
        n.parent = self

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.node_num = n
        self.root_node = None
        self.current_node = None
    def bas(self):
        n = Node("root")
        n.add_prop("this_prop_is", "set_only_root_node")
        self.root_node = n
        return self.root_node
    def bar(self):
        self.current_node = self.bas()
        for i in range(self.node_num):
            n = Node(str(i))
            self.current_node.add_child(n)
            self.current_node = n

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = Foo(5)
    f.bar()
```

In this code, it is expected that only the root node has the property whose key is "this_prop_is".
However, result of execution is like below:

```
$ python ./graph_test.py 
New node: root {}
added prop: this_prop_is set_only_root_node
New node: 0 {'this_prop_is': 'set_only_root_node'}
New node: 1 {'this_prop_is': 'set_only_root_node'}
New node: 2 {'this_prop_is': 'set_only_root_node'}
New node: 3 {'this_prop_is': 'set_only_root_node'}
New node: 4 {'this_prop_is': 'set_only_root_node'}
```

All nodes have the same key even I add it to only node "root".

I use `python 2.7.6`.

My questions are:

- Is this a bug?
- If this is not a bug, why does this occur?
- How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug. The problem is your default value for `prop`. You set it as an empty dictionary. However, this empty dictionary is copied by reference with `self.properties = prop` and when it is modified, the next time a new `Node` is created, the modified dictionary is used as the default value.

To fix this, put None as the default value and check for None when assigning properties:

```
# graph_test.py
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, name, prop=None):
        self.name = name
        self.properties = prop or {}
        self.parent = None
        self.children = []
        print "New node:", self.name, self.properties
    def add_prop(self, k, v):
        self.properties.update({k:v})
        print "added prop:", k, v
    def add_child(self, n):
        self.children.append(n)
        n.parent = self

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.node_num = n
        self.root_node = None
        self.current_node = None
    def bas(self):
        n = Node("root")
        n.add_prop("this_prop_is", "set_only_root_node")
        self.root_node = n
        return self.root_node
    def bar(self):
        self.current_node = self.bas()
        for i in range(self.node_num):
            n = Node(str(i))
            self.current_node.add_child(n)
            self.current_node = n

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = Foo(5)
    f.bar()
```

Comment: Thanks. In C++, default arguments are evaluated every function call, so it's very confusing...

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have a mutable default value in `Node.__init__`. In Python, default values are determined when the function is created, and the same instance will always be used. So every time you create a new `Node` and don't give it an explicit `prop` argument, it will use the *same* dictionary.

This is often solved by using `None` as the default value and creating a new dictionary each time inside the function if the argument is `None`, for example by doing `self.properties = prop or {}`. (This will also use a new dictionary if you give it an empty dictionary, but this isn't *usually* a problem)

Answer (score 0):

Change `props={}` to `props=None` and `self.properties = prop` to `self.properties = prop or {}`

This is due to the behavior of mutable default arguments in Python. Here's a good resource to read up on this: http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm